# Magic number in memory allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

during studying some programmatic exercises (google code jam) I came across magic number 42 with static arrays allocations even if they are used indexes from 1 to 16 or to 32.
in example:

```
     bool can[42];
     for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) can[i] = true;
```

I was thinking that can be a performance reason to doing this (memory allocation block 42*32 bits?) or something like this.
But I cant find in google any materials about this, can someone explain me whether it is related to systemic issues or only magic number 42 from Douglas Adams choose.

Comment: I bet on Douglas Adams.

Comment: life, the universe and everything http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy

Comment: Magic #.  sizeof(bool) in c++ is 1.  bool is not a datatype in c.  there's no reason to make it 42.  the compiler will probably pad it to 46.

Comment: @EdHeal Dat feeling getting a _really old nerd_!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Did not care for the restaurant either. Marvin was a damper on the occasion

Comment: @EdHeal My diodes are aching ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is 42.